# Android - custom view in action bar not clickable

Tags: android, android-actionbar, android-view

I have an `ActionBar` which has a home button and one menu item and in the middle a custom view which is a `LinearLayout` containing an `ImageView` and two `TextView` but I can't make it clickable i tried many solution with no success
even I added `clickable` attribute on the layout and the image and textview.

```
 android:clickable="true"
```

and this is my code

```
actionbar.setCustomView(R.layout.alias);
         View v=getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.alias,null);
         ImageView imageView=(ImageView) v.findViewById(R.id.profile_pic);
         imageView.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"test",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                Log.d("fff","rrr");
            }
        });
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Replace

```
View v=getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.alias,null);
```

with

```
View v = actionbar.getCustomView();
```

Try this. This should work.

Comment: @Y.S. I have the same issue in this post, your solution is not working for me http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33625277/toolbar-custom-view-cannot-clickable